# Question about using 도록 to mean "the extent of"

Tags: grammar

Does this look right?  I've been struggling with this sentence...can I combine 도록 with the 을 위하 form like this?

이런 일을 위하도록 기분이 좋지 않았다

(Intended meaning:  *I'm not feeling good enough for this kind of situation.*)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW, that sentence doesn't sound right.

First, I think -도록 doesn't just mean "to the extent", but rather "to such an extent that X happens" or "until X happens".  I just checked dic.naver.com and they have two example sentences:

> 철수는 눈만 뜨면 신이 다 닳도록 돌아다녀요.
>
> 학생들은 밤이 새도록까지 토론을 계속하였다.

(...though I'm not quite sure about adding -까지 after 새도록 in the second sentence.  It feels more natural without -까지 to me.)

Second, "위하다/위하여" is not just "for": it is more like "for the purpose of".  So "이런 일을 위하여" would be "for the purpose of such business/situation", which doesn't mesh well with "(Not) feeling good enough."

A natural expression for your intended meaning can be:

> 이런 일을 할 만한 기분이 아니었다.